# why is qDebug() needed after the reinterpret_cast?

Tags: templates, floating-point, reinterpret-cast, qdebug

In a template function, T is a typename. here the T is float. I have a ulonglong like ox41480000. According to IEEE R32.24, ox41480000 is 12.5 as a float. so I use this to convert the qlonglong to float:`T d =*reinterpret_cast<T*>(data);` where `*data=0x41480000`.

After the cast, I use the`qDebug()<<d`; to print the d and it shows 12.5 which is correct.

But if the qDebug line is commented out,the value of d becomes very strange, like 1.485e-12! Why???  (I also tried QMessageBox to print the `d` which got the same result as the qDebug.)

```
    template<typename T>

void canframeData::onRevData(qulonglong *data, unsigned int dlc)
{


    T d;

    `qulonglong revdata=*data;`
    qlonglong mask;
    mask = (m_size==(sizeof(d)<<3)? -1 : ((1ull<<m_size)-1));

    revdata=(revdata>>m_offset)&mask;
    d =*reinterpret_cast<T* >(&revdata);
    qDebug()<<"d="<<d;// get a wrong value if delete this line
    (m_pdata->*(m_pdata->pSetValue))(QVariant(d));
}
```

Comment: `qDebug` is *not required* after the `reinterpret_cast`. What is the question actually? Maybe show us a bit of code?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in a standalone compilable program? Also, have you tried to follow the execution with a debugger?

Comment: I tried it out in a standalone compilable program. There is no similar problem! It drives me crazy! In my program above, only if I put an qDebug in the function anywhere that the result of d will go right!!  Also I never use the debugger..

Comment: You must learn to use a debugger, there's no way around it.